# Linux : let process run per CPU

Tags: linux, cpu, grep

My server has 4 CPUs, and I'm parsing a file using `grep`. It's very slow using just one process.

Is it possible to let run four processes using these 4 CPUs? How to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: `grep` itself is a single threaded binary; therefore it will only use a single core at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cat bigfile.txt | parallel  --pipe grep 'pattern'
```

Or try:

```
grep -R file >> Strings
```

This is a recursive grep. Therefore it's much more intense on memory.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no parallel package.

Comment: What distro do you use? `apt-get install parallel`

Comment: This wouldn't work as the grep works on the file in order.

If you split the file first (using split 4 I think) and then ran the grep on each part, that'd grep the 4 *different* parts all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use LC_ALL=C grep -R "xyz" filename

This will speed up your search by 60%

the second option would be to use awk as below

awk '/pattern/{ print $0 }' filename

If you only want to get print out the matched word.

awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
if($i=="yyy"){print $i} } }' filename

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing at all?

Comment: It will at first Set your Language to your file default language "The Default language in which your file is written". Than pipes this result to grep which in Response donot try to find the Pattern you are looking for in many languages. using R with grep will force it recursively which is always more powerful than simple grep

Comment: @syed I've already used this, it still takes me three days to finish the parsing

Comment: oops thats too much. try awk its also good tool.

awk '/pattern/{ print $0 }' file

If you only want to get print out the matched word.

awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="yyy"){print $i} } }' file

Comment: @syed - Instead of comments update the answer. You wanted feedback on the numerous downvotes you have been getting to your answer, so you should address the problems, with your current answers to avoid additional downvotes.